# Google Analytics 4 - Refresh Token

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have developed a Testing APP (this APP has testing status because this is not published) and, as far as I am concerned, these is no other way to get a refresh_token to use this APP apart from Google Playground. Is it right?

The problem we are facing is that the token generated by Google Playgorund lasts only 7 days and we are wondering if is there any other workaround to get this refresh token without spending a few minutes weekly.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> as far as I am concerned, these is no other way to get a refresh_token to use this APP apart from Google Playground. Is it right?

Well no your supposed to write your own application to authorize to the api.  your code can authorize to the API using your client id and client screen.   [Understanding Google OAuth 2.0 with curl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w)

> The problem we are facing is that the token generated by Google Playgorund lasts only 7 days

All apps that still have a testing status in Google cloud console. Have their refresh tokens expired after seven days. This has nothing to do with Playground.

Actually my research says that what they do is just revoke the users grant to your access. This is probably faster for them then revoking any refresh tokens created.

Directly from the docs.

[experation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

If you use [Google Oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) by itself to create a refresh token. Last i checked refresh tokens would expire after only a couple of days, this is because its only intended to be used for testing not a permanent solution.

Now if you configure oauth playground using the screen below to use your personal Client id and client secret for your project you will then be restricted to the seven day refresh token as your project is still in testing.

[image]

The solution to getting a refresh token that lasts longer then seven days is to put your app into production.  TBH if your still in development / testing you really don't need a refresh token that lasts longer your test users can just authorize the app again.   A seven day refresh token is long enough to test your authorization flow within your application as access tokens expire within an hour.